# Rendering text before and after an action works

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an application with a sometimes longer executing action.  How might I, if possible, render placeholder text such as 'processing...' before the action executes and replace the page with the result of that action, given that you can only issue a render once per action?

Comment: You can't do it in controller. The simplest solution here is to use Ajax call for short actions, or Ajax polling for long time actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the :text option of the render method accepts a Proc object:

```
render :text => proc { |response, output|
   5.times do |i|
     output.write("Hello, friend\n")
     sleep 3
   end
}
```

Your example might look like :

```
 render :text => proc {|response, output|
    output.wirte("Processing..")
    results = perform_something
    output.write(results) 
 }
```

As you see, the 'output' here is an writable IO-like object. But still, you should avoid using it whenever possible. You can show the 'Processing ...' message with javascript easly here, then receive an xhr back from controller once you have the results to display

Comment: Thanks a ton, I think I'm going to go the xhr route.